# Views: Display users with a gmap attachment

Tags: 7, views, location, google-maps

I have location, gmap and profile2 modules installed on my site.
In a profile type I have added a location field so that the user can add his/her location on profile edit.

I want to display all users with a map in the header. The map will have the markers for the currently displaying users.

For this purpose I have created a page view where I displayed all the users with a pager.

Then I added an attachment and select the style format as "Gmap" and in the settings I have tried both for Data source "Location.module" and "lat/long".
And attached it to the page.

But the view does not display any map. 
Any one who have some idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [getlocation](https://www.drupal.org/project/getlocations) module. In order to show gmap with views, you need google api key. Getlocation module comes up with blocks and views with api key already embeded in code.